# Binary XML file line #24: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

im getting error while putting a vertical list view to a horizontal list view, something similar to https://appsandbiscuits.com/listview-tutorial-android-12-ccef4ead27cc
it was to create a notes app to get title and content in every list entry.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/kkkkk"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewId"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="171dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/verticalLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Title"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="Title"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_note"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="166dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="180dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:onClick="buttonPressed"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/listViewId" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

i'm new to android development and it would really appreciate the help

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you cannot direct add child view inside the `ListView` directly. In your case, you are adding `ImageView` and `LinearLayout` as direct children of `ListView`. Due to this, you are getting a Runtime exception. (Ref: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java;l=488 )

In Android, you are supposed to use adapter to add view inside `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. I would suggest you to look into **Video tutorials** instead of blog posts, since blog posts are super confusing about which code goes where.

Answer (score 0):

Just use LinearLayout instead of ListView (I believe it is a typo).